# Onclick doesn't work in userscript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

there is an element in the page:

```
<div action="storage" class="item_menu storage_menu ajax_action 
header_menu_item tc">Menu</div>
```

And the idea is to make an alert when somebody clicks on it.
The code i now use:

```
document.getElementByClass("storage_menu").onclick = alert("Норм");
```

doesn't work. 
Could someone please explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: There is no getElementByClass and you are calling alert and assigning what it returns to the event listener....

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to all these classes and listeners